Lenovo T14s: Dual WQHD monitors going randomly black
I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T14s docked to the official USB-C dock and this is connected to two Display port (DP) monitors via one cable (daisy chaining). I use this method because I have another '(private) computer which is connected to the other DP port of the first monitor. On the second computer this does not happen, so the monitors and daisy chaining itself works.
It happens from every second (this occurred only once, luckily), to avery few minutes to 2 times per hour. Not always both screens are going black but very often. After a few seconds they are showing the picture again.
This problem occurred in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS , but now I'm running 24.04 LTS and it became even more frequently.
I've already tried

installing intels GPU drivers
disabling the "turbo" state of the CPU as mentioned here
checking cables
removed `~/.config/monitors.xml'
apt update && apt upgrade`, also Updated the dock firmware.
disabled fractional scaling, I use Wayland.

nothing helped.
In the office, we have the same dock but the monitors are Full HD only. Here, the blacking does not happen.

I've bought a used (refurbished) monitor. The cable delivered with this monitor was cause of the problem, the nice-looking nylon coating does not prevent cable breaks.
